# SQL to Consolidate table with lots of custom user fields against each user ID

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, database

I have a database table like so:

| user_id | field_id | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first_name | Jim |
| 1 | last_name | Bob |
| 1 | postcode | 12345 |
| 2 | first_name | Joe |
| 2 | last_name | Blogs |
| 2 | postcode | 67890 |

I need to convert it to the format below, converting the custom fields to columns and deduplicating the user ids.

| user_id | first_name | last_name | postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | Bob | 12345 |
| 2 | Joe | Blogs | 67890 |

How can I do this in SQL and how would you describe technically what it is I'm trying to do? I can't think of the right terminology to search for a solution to this.

I have over 20 custom fields, which may change over time so a scalable solution would be nice, but I don't mind writing a manual query for for my current setup just to get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is an UNPIVOT, on user_Id and field_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when field_id = 'first_name' then field_value end) as first_name,
       max(case when field_id = 'last_name' then field_value end) as last_name,
       max(case when field_id = 'postcode' then field_value end) as postcode
from test_tbl
group by user_id;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=011cda2d96b23a09b7ed42bc5f5e085f)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT user_id, 
       t1.field_value first_name, 
       t2.field_value last_name, 
       t3.field_value postcode
FROM tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 USING (user_id)
JOIN tablename t3 USING (user_id)
WHERE t1.field_id = 'first_name'
  AND t2.field_id = 'last_name'
  AND t3.field_id = 'postcode';
```

or

```sql
SELECT user_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 'first_name' THEN field_value END) first_name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 'last_name' THEN field_value END) last_name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 'postcode' THEN field_value END) postcode
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id;
```